# Knockout.mapping: Does it make ALL nested objects observable?

Tags: knockout.js, mapping, observable

I am really new to Knockoutjs (and not very good with javascript in general) and am trying to map all possible nested objects of a JSON object so that each and everyone is observable. I was under the impression that the use of ko.mapping.fromJS would result in all objects and their objects observable. However, I am not seeing that happen.

What I've put in jsfiddle isn't quite what I am really doing but it does demonstrate that I am trying to map an object and then bind the nested value to an HTML span.

http://jsfiddle.net/Eves/L5sgW/32/  <- EDIT: Updated this to the appropriate jsfiddle

HTML

```
<p> <span>Name:</span>
<span data-bind="text:  IntroData.Name))"></span>
</p>
```

JS

```
$(function () {

var ViewModel = function (data) {
    var me = this;
    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, me);

    return me;
};

var stuff = {
    IntroData: {
        Name: 'Test'
    }
};
window.viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(new ViewModel(stuff));
ko.applyBindings(window.viewModel);
});
```

Is it just that I have to make use of mapping options to have the nested objects be made observable? If so, what if the JSON object is so vast and complex (this one obviously isn't)? Can some recursive functionality be used to loop through each object's nested objects to make them all observable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues with your code snippet and jsfiddle:

- the fiddle doesn't include the mapping plugin
- the fiddle doesn't include jQuery (but the jQuery-specific code can be removed anyhow)
- the span element is self closing but shouldn't be
- the mapping plugin expects "extra mapping options" as the second argument, the `me` should be a third argument
- you're missing the `InitialLoadOfApplication` function on your model (though I'm unclear what its purpose would be)
- your `text` binding on the span has two stray parentheses that shouldn't be there

If I fix all those issues I end up with the following (see also [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ry5bA/)):

```html
<p> 
    <span>Name:</span>
    <span data-bind="text: IntroData.PlanName"></span>
    <button id="update" data-bind="click: InitialLoadOfApplication">Update!</button> 
</p>
```

And this Javascript:

```
var ViewModel = function (data) {
    var me = this; 
    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, me);

    me.InitialLoadOfApplication = function() { alert('loading!'); };

    return me;
};

var stuff = {
    IntroData: {
        PlanName: 'Test'
    }
};

window.viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(new ViewModel(stuff));
ko.applyBindings(window.viewModel);
```

Regarding your question, the mapping plugin can handle rather complex objects in my experience. If you reach its boundries there's always the "extra mapping info" to handle edge cases. [The relevant documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html) does a great job explaining those.

Comment: I seemed to have butchered my jsfiddle. The version you worked on does not reflect the one I meant to share. Here is the real one: http://jsfiddle.net/Eves/L5sgW/32/

Comment: Are you sure? It looks mightily similar, has almost the same set of problems (and [solution](http://jsfiddle.net/L5sgW/35/)).

Comment: That last link I provided doesn't have a button or mention of InitialLoadOfApplication.

Comment: Yep, you're right. I was missing some of the things you mentioned. I suspect this test is not a very good reflection of my real problem. Let me check a few things

Comment: That's fine. You may want to consider starting a new question if it's rather different from this one. Good luck!

Comment: Funny....I was just about to ask if that would be appropriate. Thanks for the info. As far as this exact question is concerned you answered it.